# RecycleView output all null

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I wanna ask regarding this recycleview issues, my code doesnt show any problem,but why my recycleview output became like this [RecycleView Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6C7m.png). I had tried by change `switch case()` to `if else()` but it will give error if I write throw `new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value:" + data.getItem()); at the end of else.` The app will crash and stop running if I did not commend the exception. When I still using `switch case`, it will came out an error of `NullException`

This is my code:
MainActivity() code

```
package com.example.assignment;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextView textView;
    private Button AddBtn;
    private Button signOutBtn;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private DatabaseReference ref;
    private String userID  = "";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Data> dataList;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);


        textView=findViewById(R.id.totalAmount);
        AddBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_new);


        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("expenses").child(userID);




        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        AddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                addItem();
            }
        });

        recyclerView =findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(MainActivity.this, dataList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

        readItems();

//        signOutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
//            }
//        });



    }

    private void readItems(){

        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String date = format.format(calendar.getTime());

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("expenses").child(userID);
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("date").equalTo(date);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                dataList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Data data = snapshot.getValue(Data.class);
                    dataList.add(data);
                }

                itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                int totalAmount = 0;
                for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue();
                    Object total = map.get("amount");
                    int getTotal = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(total));
                    totalAmount+=getTotal;

                    textView.setText("Total Spending : RM" + totalAmount);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }


    private void addItem() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //LayoutInflater layout = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        LayoutInflater layout = getLayoutInflater();

        View view = layout.inflate(R.layout.input_layout, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.inputLayout));
        setContentView(view);

        final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        final Spinner spinnerItem = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category));
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerItem.setAdapter(adapter);

        final EditText amount = view.findViewById(R.id.insert_amount);
        final EditText notes = view.findViewById(R.id.insert_note);
        final Button saveButton = view.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        final Button cancelButton = view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String amountGet = amount.getText().toString();
                String notesGet = notes.getText().toString();
                String categoryGet = spinnerItem.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.error);

                if(amountGet.isEmpty()){
                    amount.setError("Please enter an amount!!!", icon );
                    return;
                }

                if(notesGet.isEmpty()){
                    notes.setError("Please enter a notes!!!", icon );
                    return;
                }

                if(categoryGet.equals("Select a Category")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please select a valid category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Had added the information into database");
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    progressDialog.show();

                    String id = ref.push().getKey();

                    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String date = format.format(calendar.getTime());

                    Data inform = new Data(categoryGet, date, id, notesGet, Integer.parseInt(amountGet));
                    ref.child(id).setValue(inform).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Information added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to add the information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
                }

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });



    }



}
```

ItemsAdapter() code

```
package com.example.assignment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class ItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdapter.viewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Data> dataList;

    public ItemsAdapter(Context context, List<Data> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.output_layout, parent, false);
        //return new ItemsAdapter.viewHolder(view);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Data data = dataList.get(position);
        holder.category.setText("Category :" + data.getItem());
        holder.amount.setText("Amount :" + data.getAmount());
        holder.date.setText("Date :" + data.getDate());
        holder.notes.setText("Note :" + data.getNotes());


//        switch(data.getItem()){
//
//            case "Petrol Spend":
//                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.petrol);
//                break;
//
//            case "Groceries Spend":
//                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.grocery);
//                break;
//
//            case "eWallet Transaction":
//                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wallet);
//                break;
//
//            case "Other Eligible Spend":
//                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.spend);
//                break;
//
//            default:
//                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value:" + data.getItem());
//        }

        if(data.getItem() == "Petrol Spend"){
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.petrol);

        }else if(data.getItem() == "Groceries Spend"){
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.grocery);

        }else if(data.getItem() == "eWallet Transaction"){
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wallet);

        }else if(data.getItem() == "Other Eligible Spend"){
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.spend);
        }
        //else throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value:" + data.getItem());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView category, amount, date, notes;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            amount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            notes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400** (four hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
dataList.add(data);
itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Try this:

```
// add this in the place of dataList.add(data)
adapter.setDataList(data);

// Add this setter inside the adapter;
setDataList(List<Data> datalist){
  this.dataList = dataList;
  notifyItemChanged(0,dataList);
}
```